# Will async.forEach() run through new elements I add to the array if its still executing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

My question is:

If I import the async module, create an array, write a async.forEach() loop for that array, and while the loop runs, I put more elements in that array for it to loop through, will it process those newly added elements?

Comment: What about wrapping it in a `while`/`for` conditional statement that checks the length of the array.  That way, you can trigger a `breakfor` and include the newly added array item within the iteration as needed...

Comment: Even that is possible, I don't think it is a safe way to do so.

Comment: Is there a fairly simple and safe way to do this then?

Comment: @AveryCoolGuy Well if you use an async method with a for inside and the added items are always at the latest indexes it will work... however that's simple but not reliable and all of this sounds weird to me =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't modify the collection while the foreach is running, so it will not loop through your new items =(